# Sound design that "shows what we haven't seen"?

Tags: philosophy

This is a reiteration of an old idea about art's function being "to show us what we haven't seen" or "show what we didn't know that we had to see".

Keeping this in mind. Do you have examples of where sound design is at the level of influency and "instructionism" in the sense that it portrays things "we didn't know we had to hear".

And to keep the question non-subjective and out of merely listing subjective "influential sound design" examples, what is "instructive sound design" like?

Answer (score 1):

I can personally say that sound, even the recorded one, changes everytime you hear it. It's a deeper thing than images. What sound teaches you comes from within you.
These days I find listening Brian Eno and Harold Budd's "The pearl" (in particular the senconth track) surfing over an immense river of milk.
To better answer your question, sound to me doesn't pretend to teach you something, it suggests you something: you have to get there.